# The fastest way to render huge amount of rectangles in iOS?

Tags: ios, performance, render, calayer

I have a lot of small rects, opaque, solid colored, not overlapping, with frequently changing position and size. Rendering them in different ways always produces lags on real devices. I've tried the following methods:

- render all via `CGContext` in `draw(inRect:)` method
- use individual `CAShapeLayer` instances for each rect
- use `CALayer` instances with pre-rendered content - the best in performance but produces artifacts on borders when rects are scaling
- `UIimageView` instances with small pre-generated images

Also tried to adjust various `CALayer` options (ex. `edgeAntialiasingMask`, `drawsAsynchronously`, `shouldRasterize`...), but still couldn't eliminate lags.

[image: example]

So, is there working approach to do that and get no/minimum lags?

**Update with measurements and answer**

Thanks to @Saurav for the tip in comments, I've found with Time Profiles that `UIView.convert(rect: to:)` method eats 35% of CPU time, and `UIView.setFrame(...)` eats another 15%.

Rendering itself doesn't eat significant CPU time when refreshing frames - checked for approaches via `draw(inRect:)` and pre-rendered `UIImageView`.

Comment: Use OpenGL or, if all your target devices support it, Metal.

Comment: That looks like less than 1000 rectangles. That doesn't seem like a lot (I've drawn over 5000 lines on an old iPad 3 at 60fps using standard Core Graphics w/o lag). I would first suspect your layout algorithm. What are you seeing from Instruments? Are you CPU bound? Why do you think it's the drawing itself? This does seem to be exactly what `CALayer` is built for. I don't understand why you would pre-render, though, to just have a simple background color. (That said, if you can get your computations under control, I'd probably implement w/ `draw(inRect:)`)

Comment: @robmayoff I forgot to mention, OpenGL is very edge case because it lives in separate 'world'. hope to find more `UIView`-friendly approach

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for comment. I've measured CPU time and it's really bound by UI geometry methods, not rendering itself. I've updated entire question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed these:
1. Avoid creating multiple instances of CALayer or UIView.
2. Create all 1000s of layers or views once inside viewDidLoad and update the frame whenever needed.

Calculation of frames which you are doing may be blocking the thread.

Comment: of course, I create all instances only once at loading time. The lags exist while I'm updating frames.

Comment: It might be the calculation of frames which you are doing, blocking the thread. how are you calculating the frames?

Comment: you are completely right! Strange that I missed this scope when investigated the issue. Certainly the heaviest method was `convert(rect: to:)`. I've updated the question with measurement data

Comment: Awesome! So is it working as fine now? If so, I will update my answer.

Comment: yeah, the reason was in heady frames calculation.